# Approximation to $\sqrt{\cos(\theta)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, approximation

I have this formula, (it is just the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) angle formula):

$$
d = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \ cos(\theta)}
$$

Here is my issue. I am wondering if there is a way to 'extract' the $cos$ term. My motivation here is because I want to show that $d$ is in fact sinusoidal - or perhaps very close to sinusoidal - as $\theta$ is varied, while $a$ and $b$ are fixed.

So, might there be a way to simplify, or 'extract' the $cos$ term here? What is the approximation to $\sqrt{cos(\theta)}$? Thank you.

Comment: did you try to use series?

Comment: @Bilou06 I did not, I am not sure I would know how...

Comment: To simplify, your expression, you need :

$$cos(x) = \sum _{{n=0}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}}x^{{2n}}$$

$$(1+x)^{\alpha }=1+\sum _{{n=1}}^{{\infty }}{\alpha  \choose n}x^{n}$$

and to compare with sinusoidal:

$$sin(x) = \sum _{{n=0}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}}x^{{2n+1}}$$

Comment: Expressions like this are not truly sinusoidal, even if they are perodic. It's "famously" known that the arc length formula for an ellipse defined by $(a\cos(t),b\sin(t))$ does not yield an elementary result for $a\neq b$. The integral is $\int\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}\,dt$. The Pythagorean identity and double angle identity can be used to manipulate this into the form $\int\sqrt{A+B\cos(2t)}\,dt$, which is like your expression. So if your expression were purely sinusoidal, we would be able to integrate it, contradicting that it is well-know this cannot be integrated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's rather simple 
$$d = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \ cos(\theta)}$$
$$d^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \ cos(\theta)$$
$$ d^2 - a^2 - b^2=2ab \ cos(\theta)$$
$$ \frac{d^2 - a^2 - b^2}{2ab} = \ cos(\theta)$$
$$ \frac{d^2}{2ab} - \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2ab} = \ cos(\theta)$$
and since $a$ and $b$ are fixed, $k = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2ab}$
$$ \ cos(\theta) = \frac{d^2}{2ab} -k$$
with $d\leq a+b$ for the *triangle inequality*.

Finally $\sqrt{cos(\theta)} = \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{2ab} - \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2ab}}$

Anyway, assuming $a=b$ for simplicity, $$d=a\sqrt{2-2\cos(\theta)}=2|sin(\frac{\theta}{2})|$$ and this shows why $d$ is *sinusoidal*.

Furthermore, let $a=b+k$, then $$d = \sqrt{a^2 + a^2 +2ak+k^2 - 2a(a+k) \ cos(\theta)}$$
$$ d = \sqrt{2a^2-2a^2\cos\theta+2ak-2ak\cos\theta+k^2} $$
$$ d = \sqrt{2a^2(1-\cos\theta)+2ak(1-\cos\theta)+k^2} $$
$$ d = \sqrt{2a^2(2\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})+2ak(2\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})+k^2} $$
$$ d = \sqrt{4a^2\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})+4ak\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})+k^2} $$

which does have a *sinusoidal* pattern, but it's more difficult to unveil when $k \ne 0$

Comment: Hmm, but how does this show that $d$ is sinusoidal, or near sinusoidal?

Comment: I'm finishing the answer, the first part is only to explicit $d$...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show that $d(\theta)$ is sinusoidal, just compute its derivative which is $$\frac{a b \sin (\theta)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2 a b \cos (\theta)}}$$ and see how the function behaves (maximum, minimum, symmetry, period,..).

Comment: Well, I happen to know that the result *looks* sinusoidal, but the $sqrt$ makes me uneasy about how truly sinusoidal it is..

Comment: Truly truly ! Look at the function values for $\theta=0$, $\theta=\pi/2$, $\theta=\pi$ and so on. Cheers.

Comment: Not sure I follow how/why this should work... may you please expand on your answer? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an approach to your problem is to let $a=b$ for simplicity so
$$
d = \sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab \cos x} = a \sqrt{2-2\cos x}
$$
and then just plot the function $f(x) = \sqrt{2-2\cos x}$, getting
[image: sqrtPlot]

which is clearly a wave, but not sure how sinusoidal it is.

It is, however, similar to a similar transformation of the sine, just off by a horizontal translation, it seems. Here is the plot of $\sqrt{2-2\cos x}, \sqrt{2-2\sin x}$ on the same axis:

[image: 2xfrms]

Comment: $1 - \cos x = 2\sin^{2}(\frac{x}{2})$, so $f(x) = 2\left|\sin(\frac{x}{2})\right|$. :)

Comment: @user86418 indeed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function that describes the distance of a fixed point from a point travelling on a circle cannot be perfectly "sinusoidal", since it exhibits discontinuities for the derivatives, as shown by @gt6989b, for instance. However we can state that the coefficients of the Fourier cosine series of
$$ f(\theta) = \sqrt{1-\lambda \cos\theta}, $$ 
where we set $\lambda=\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}\leq 1$, decay pretty fast, giving good approximations of $f(\theta)$ in terms of even trigonometric polynomials. The coefficient of $\cos(n\theta)$ in the Fourier cosine series of $f(\theta)$ is:
$$ c_n = -2\sqrt{\lambda+1}\left(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)^n\cdot\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n-1)8^n}\cdot\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\frac{2n-1}{2},\frac{2n+1}{2};2n+1;\frac{2\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right),$$
and the hypergeometric term can be quite trivially bounded by $\left(\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}\right)^{n/2}$. This gives reasonable bounds when $a$ and $b$ are pretty different, so $\lambda$ is pretty far from $1$. In the opposite case, it is worth considering that:
$$g(a,b,\theta)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta}=\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4ab\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}}$$ 
is always between $2\sqrt{ab}\cdot\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|$ and $2\sqrt{ab}\cdot\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|+\frac{(a-b)^2}{4\sqrt{ab}\cdot\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|}$, and we can refine the upper bound by applying the Newton method to the convex function $x^2-\left((a-b)^2+4ab\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$ by choosing the previous upper bound as a starting point. For any $\theta$ far enough from $0$ and $2\pi$, this works just nice. For a uniform bound, we can use a continued fraction, since:
$$ \sqrt{x^2+\varepsilon^2} = x + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{x+\sqrt{x^2+\varepsilon^2}}=x+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2x+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2x+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{\ldots}}}.$$